# UISearchBar with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I added a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController with a UINavigationController.  Because we needed a few buttons in the navigationBar, I created a custom view that contains a few buttons, and put that as the rightBarButtonItem.  I notice when I click on the search bar, the keyboard pops up from the bottom, and also moves the UINavigationController's navigationBar off the screen.  So now I cannot see what I enter in my UISearchBar.  Is there a way to get around this?  I've seen other apps that it looks like they use a UINavigationBar + multiple buttons on the LHS or RHS of the navigationBar, so I'm assuming this is possible.  Thanks.

```
UIButton *homeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
UIImage *house = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_house.png"];
[homeButton setImage:house forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *filterButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(49, 0, 44, 44)];
[filterButton setTitle:@"Filter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FilterButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.SearchEntry = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(98, 0, 150, 44)] autorelease];
self.SearchEntry.delegate = self;
UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayCtlr = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchEntry contentsController:self];
searchDisplayCtlr.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchDisplayCtlr.searchResultsDelegate = self;
searchDisplayCtlr.delegate = self;


UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 248, 44)];
[containerView addSubview:homeButton];
[containerView addSubview:filterButton];
[containerView addSubview:_searchEntry];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adjust the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`. Also please take care of the **Hierarchy** of the controls you have taken. Dont keep `UINavigationBar` and `UISearchView` in `ScrollView`, then it will not move and remains fixed in their position